# Is Google Reader for Android open source project?

Tags: android, open-source

Would like to see how they've implemented their widget (at least - widget layout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and there's not even an official API (but there are some *unofficial* APIs).

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=77997087618e7e24&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=393ffb7b02daff26&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=1f32659d6e5f8c90&hl=en

**Edit**: To see the layout, you can use APK Manager and read the xmls:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695701

Comment: +1 thanks for the point to APK Manager. Good tool to know about.

Comment: @slund if you're interested in APK Manager, this post may be interesting to you also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656804/whats-the-best-way-to-learn-smali-and-how-when-to-use-dalvik-vm-opcodes/5656979#5656979

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've already found APK Manager yesterday. Btw, why moders think that this post is not related to coding???

Comment: @LA_ most probably because the way you wrote it. I can't edit it since it's closed, but I would try to rewrite it as "How is Google Reader widget implemented? Is there an open API? Is its source code available? If not, what are the options to implement a similar layout?" (to make it more clear that you're looking for a way to implement something similar). I understood your point, but most probably they didn't. You can flag it an explain the misunderstanding and your intentions to edit the question, but it's probably not worth now for this one. I don't have the rep to reopen it.